# Why is my Model object always null on my Razor Page in dotnet core 2.x Razor Page app?

Tags: model, .net-core, razor-pages

I'm creating a Partial View as a part of my Index.cshtml.
I am following the basics outlined in the Microsoft article => https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/partial?view=aspnetcore-2.1

The summary of it is that I'm :
Adding a span to my Index.cshtml file which is actually loaded with the HTML from a Razor Page. 
The relevant HTML in Index.cshtml looks like the following:

```
<span id="basicView">
    @{ 
        Model.UserName = "IndexUser";
        await Html.RenderPartialAsync("BasicPartial", Model);
    }
</span>
```

I have added public property to my IndexModel named UserName in the RazorPage and it looks like the following:

```
namespace FirstCore.Pages
{
    public class IndexModel : PageModel
    {

        public string UserName;
        public void OnGet()
        {

        }
    }
}
```

It is kept very simple for this example.
So, in the HTML in the Index.cshtml you can see that I set the value of that public property to "IndexUser" and then I pass the name of the Razor Page ("BasicPartial" - View) and the Model object to the BasicaPartial Razor Page.

The BasicPartial page is very simple -- was generated from the Visual Studio 2017 template - Add...Razor Page...  The entire things looks like:

```
@page
@model IndexModel
@*
    For more information on enabling MVC for empty projects, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=397860
*@
<div>This is the text and the user name is @(Model.UserName).</div>
```

Actually, the only important part is the  and the place where I'm reading the property value of UserName out of the passed in Model.
You can see I've also defined the @model as an IndexModel at the top.

**The Main Problem - Model is ALWAYS Null**

When I run this very simple example.  The application tells me that the Model object is null.

[image: Model is null]

You may believe that it is the UserName that is null, but if I put a very simple directive at the top like

```
<div>@Model</div>
```

Then it tells me that Model is null, even though I know I'm passing it in.

Do you know why it is null?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

If I make one change to the BasicPartial.cshtml file then the Model is no longer null.

All I have to do is remove the @page directive so the BasicPartial.cshtml file now looks like the following:

```
@model IndexModel
@*
    For more information on enabling MVC for empty projects, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=397860
*@
<div>This is the text and the user name is @(Model.UserName).</div>
```

Now it works perfectly.  The Model object is a the valid object with the property value set as expected.  (See highlighted text in the image below.)

[image: model is no longer null]

Comment: thanks for the tip about removing @page directive, that ended up being my issue.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know.  I figured someone else had to stumble on this too and I was wondering why I hadn't heard or seen more people mentioning it.  Glad it helped.

Comment: I spend 4 hours on this bs. Figured the generated content should be fine, since I the "Add view" wizard did the job. Props to MS.

Comment: @Kimmax Yeah, I wasted a number of hours trying to resolve the issue too. It drove me crazy. And you're right, you don't expect the problem since this is code added by the template.

Answer (score 9):

As [OP pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50023167/3838167), removing the @page directive will fix things.

[From the docs for @page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/razor-pages/?view=aspnetcore-3.0&tabs=visual-studio)

> @page makes the file into an MVC action - which means that it handles requests directly, without going through a controller.

In other words, your controller wasn't actually being used, **despite being called*.**
 <sub>*At least in my case, my controller was called . I did not test OP's code</sub>

Certainly a flawed design.

Comment: spent 45mins trying to figure out whats wrong with my partial. thanks for this answer i can climb out the rabbit hole now.