# Setup correctly a razor page to have access to data in code-behind

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, razor-pages, code-behind

I'm new with Razor Pages and I found out that code can be divided using code-behind file. So I created this Index class to initialize my date and print them to the `.cshtml` file. But when I try to compile and run it, I get an reror

> 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

when I try to use `@Model.date`.

I understood that the variable are not initialized cause OnGet method is never called. But it should be called when the page is requested right?So why variable are never initialize? I start the project in localhost with visual studio so i want only to print the data.
First of all, when I put the code inside the Razor page without using the class `Index` it worked as I expected. When I tried to move to the next step in the learning path, I am just stuck.

```
@page
@model SportData.Web.Views.Home.Index

<div class="date">
    <h1>Aggiornamento lista in data @Model.date</h1> --> error here
 
</div>
```

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;

namespace SportData.Web.Views.Home
{
    public class Index : PageModel
    {
        List<string> months = new List<string>();
        public DateTime date { get; set; }

        public int num = 4; --> also this give the same error if i try to put in the h1 tag
        public DateTime specificDate { get; set; }
         
        public void OnGet() {
            date = DateTime.Now;
            specificDate = new DateTime(2022, 08, 01);
        }
    }
}
```

with debug:
[image: link to screen of debug result]

Comment: Do the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50023096/120955) answer your question?

Comment: Wich file i should be check to be sure to find the problem?? Cause this is all i have in Index.cshtml and Index.cshtml.cs

Comment: @mxmissile i also create a new project and put this simple line of code but nothing change.

Comment: @StriplingWarrior i tried to remove '@page' but still not work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So I created this Index class to initialize my date and print them to
> the .cshtml file. But when I try to compile and run it, I get an error:
>
> > Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
>
> When I tried to move to the next step in the learning path, I am just stuck.

You are getting the exception because of your incorrect reference on your view: `@model SportData.Web.Views.Home.Index`

You should use your reference as  [`@model Index`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/razor-pages/?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=visual-studio#razor-pages) so your view should be as following:

```
@page
@model Index

<div class="date">
    <h1>Aggiornamento lista in data @Model.date</h1>
 
</div>
```

[image]

[You can get more details here in this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/razor-pages/?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=visual-studio#razor-pages)

**Output:**

[image]

**Note:** If you need more implementation samples, you can check [the official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/razor-pages/?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=visual-studio#razor-pages)

Comment: I tried to create a simple ASP.NET Web project in VS with a razor pages by default and it work correctly. 
So, when i try to put the same pattern as your solution and the default(by VS) it doesn't change anything. 

The problem is that the project is a an ASP.NET Web (MVC) type?i don't have a 'Pages' folder but 'View' . And Program.cs is different, but adding 'builder.Services.AddRazorPages();' and '
app.MapRazorPages();' doen't change anything

Comment: You haven't mensioned that you are integrating razor page in `asp.net core MVC` project. However, [`you can follow the instruction here`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2017/september/asp-net-core-simpler-asp-net-mvc-apps-with-razor-pages)

Comment: Yes, the problem was the idea of mix 2 patterns. I don't really needed this type of solution. Owever the link was so usefull to understand that. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

<sub>Moving OP's solution from the question to an answer:</sub>

> The problem was that I created an ASP.NET MVC project and I tried to implement the Razor pattern inside it. The simplest way to interact with Razor Pages in an MVC project is by the Controller and not via Model created as code-behind.